# Trouble setting and retrieving value of hidden input fields of iframe

Tags: javascript, hidden-fields, frameset-iframe

I am having trouble either to set or retrieve the hidden input fields information of iframe.

On the initial page, I click on "Submit" button to activate showBox function and pass three parameters, name, city, and state successfully. showBox creates a popup box where an iframe should sit on top of the box and do form manipulation. I need to set the value of the three hidden input fields with the value passed from the showBox function. Here is the code for showbox function -

```
 function showBox(name, city, state)
  {  
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.zIndex = 1;
    div.id = 'box';
    div.style.position = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 6') > -1) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
    div.style.top = '20px';
    div.style.left = (width / 2) - (900 / 2) + 'px'; 
    div.style.height = '500px';
    div.style.width = '400px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    div.style.border = '2px solid silver';
    div.style.padding = '20px';
    document.body.appendChild(div);  

    alert("Name: " + name + ", City: " + city + ", State: " + state);

    div.innerHTML = "<iframe id='infopage' src='" + 'info.html' + "' width='100%' height='95%'></iframe>";  

    // set value of the hidden input fields
    var myname = $("#infopage #hiddenname").val(name);
    var mycity = $("#infopage #hiddencity").val(city);
    var mystate = $("#infopage #hiddenstate").val(state);

        // check hidden input fields value - which come back blank so far
    alert("Name from hidden field: " + $("#hiddenname").val() + ", City from hidden field: " + $("#hiddencity").val() + ", State from hidden field: " + $("#hiddenstate").val()); 

    // create close window link
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = '<br /><br />Close window';
    a.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
    a.onclick = function() 
    {      
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('box'));
    };

    div.appendChild(a);
  }
```

Even though the parameters value got passed to the showBox function successfully, some how I just could not successfully set hidden input fields value with the parameters.

Meanwhile, here is the code for info.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample person information</title> 
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">        
        @import "css/core.css"; 
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jsonreport.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/info.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="full_width big" id="testname">
                <br /> 
            <!--    (it may take a while to load large files) -->
        </div>
        <br />

            <input type="text" name="hiddenname" id="hiddenname" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddencity" id="hiddencity" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenstate" id="hiddenstate" value=""/>
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="  Enter  " />

        <div id="AjaxDiv"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When click on the "Enter" button, an ajax function will be called using the hidden fields value from the iframe. Somehow I have difficult retrieving the hidden input fields value from the iframe also.

Comment: Please format your code and, where possible, remove lines that are not essential to reproducing your problem.

Comment: I placed my code on Fiddle. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/qpMHf/4/ for the code. Somehow I just cannot set or retrieve the hidden input fields value from iframe.

Answer (score 0):

from the code you posted here and on fiddler,
i see that showbox() is not called,
so the iframe is never created?

also try replacing your submit button with this ( to test if it works )

```
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('infopage').src);return false;" value="  Enter  " />
```

Comment: The showbox() was called by <a href="javascript:void(showBox("Frank", "San Francisco", "CA"))">Person Info</a> of the caller program, which I do not have problem pass the three parameters through the showbox function. When apply the following statements -
 var myiframe = document.getElementById('infopage');
 var frame = myiframe.contentDocument.getElementById('hiddenname');
 
 alert("my iframe id: " + myiframe.id + ", frame: " + frame); - give back "my iframe id: infopage, frame: null"
 alert($("#infopage").contents().find("#hiddenname").val("Frank")); - give back "[object Object]"

Comment: could you edit your question and add this code to it ?
you will have more chances to get an answer.

Comment: In index.html http://jsfiddle.net/qpMHf/10/ for code -
• When click “Create my popup with iframe” link, a js function showBox(name, city, state) is called, passes values of “hidname”, “hidcity” and state value “ca” while a popup box is created. 
• Inside the box is a div tag contains iframe with test. Html. 
• Problems: need to use the data passed in through showBox to set the value of three input fields on test.html for further process. How to access the text input fields of test.html page inside of iframe, so I can store the passing data to “hiddenname”, “hiddencity”, and “hiddenstate”?

Comment: Finally I was able to set the form input fields value of iframe by using the following statements -
var ifr = $('#infopage');  // id of iframe
 ifr.contents().find("body #hiddenname").val(name).val();
 ifr.contents().find("body #hiddencity").val(city).val();
 ifr.contents().find("body #hiddenstate").val(state).val();
 The code work with Firefox and IE, but does not work with Chrome.
I got the information from http://www.zimbio.com/ASP.Net/articles/gsuiDzNz1rz/Jquery+get+set+read+access+IFrame+content